# Modeling regulations of middlemen

Tags: finance-mathematics, market-microstructure, financial-markets

I am searching for some paper that models the regulations of market makers in stock or OTC markets. Is there anybody who have seen some marekt microstructure paper for modeling regulations and what are these regulations? Since the crises of 2009 occured, many regulations have changed in the stock and OTC markets. I am trying to find some textbook of micro or some paper that deals with modeling in such issues